# Using conditional probability to calculate the probability an employee that is a woman resigned from a particular store

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Problem Statement: Stores A B and C have 50, 75, and 100 employees, respectively, and 50, 60, and 70 percent of them respectively are women. Resignations are equally likely among all employees, regardless of sex. One woman employee resigns. What is the probability that she works in store C?

My attempt at a solution:
Let A,B,C denote the event an employee works at store A,B,C respectively. Let R denote the event an employee resigns. Let W denote the event that an employee is a woman.
Then, P(A) = 50/225, P(B) = 75/225, P(C) = 100/225, P(W|A) = .5, P(W|B) = .6, P(W|C) = .7, and P(R|{X}} = 1/|{X}| for any event X in the sample space. For example, the probability that an employee resigns given that they are a woman that worked at store A is P(R|AW) = 1/25.

In the context of my definitions, we seek P(C|RW).

I attempted the following:

P(C|RW) = P(RCW)/P(RW)

Let's calculate P(RW) first.

P(RW) = P(RWA U RWB U RWC) = P(RWA) + P(RWB) + P(RWC) = P(A)P(W|A)P(R|WA) + P(B)P(W|B)P(R|WB) + P(C)P(W|C)P(R|WC) = (50/225)(.5)(1/25) + (75/225)(.6)(1/45) + (100/225)(.7)(1/70)

Now, I can see that the way I've defined my events is a problem, but I don't understand why. For example, each term in the preceding sum just becomes 1/225. I can see mathematically why but I don't understand where I'm going wrong as far as my formulas or my definitions of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n(W\cap A) = 50*0.5 = 25$

$n(W\cap B) = 75*0.6 = 51$

$n(W\cap C) = 100*0.7 = 70 .....n(W)= 146$

Since resignations are equally likely, hence proportional to numbers,

$P(W\cap C|R) = \frac{n(W\cap C)}{n{(W)}}= \frac{70}{146}$

Comment: Thanks, I saw a solution to this and it makes sense. But wondering where in my approach I went wrong.

Comment: $P(R|AW) \neq \frac 1{25}$, it is $P(AW) /[P(AW)+P(BW)+P(CW)]$